# GNUmakefile unable to be executed. Windows 10, Visual Studio Code. **GNUmakefile:5: ../GNUmakefile: No such file or directory make: ***

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

Using **VisualStudioCode on Windows 10**, I cannot figure out to execute my **GNUmakefile** provided by my Professor for this assignment to create a shell. Currently, I am attempting to run "make" in my project workspace. The following error message is being produced when the following command was executed:

```
PS C:\Users\MKyle\VSWorkspace\CS452-Homework3> make
GNUmakefile:5: ../GNUmakefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '../GNUmakefile'.  Stop.
```

**GNUmakefile:5: ../GNUmakefile: No such file or directory make: *** No rule to make target '../GNUmakefile'.  Stop.**

GNUmakefile exists in the project workspace but when "make" is run in the terminal, it doesn't seem to be able to connect to the GNUmakefile. The contents of the GNUmakefile are shown below.

```
prog=shell

ldflags:=-lreadline -lncurses

include ../GNUmakefile

try: $(objs) libdeq.so
    gcc -o $@ $(objs) $(ldflags) -L. -ldeq -Wl,-rpath=.

trytest: try
    Test/run

test: $(prog)
    Test/run
```

The contents of the Workspace which includes GNUmakefile can be found in these images below.

[VSCode Workspace Contents Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE0Ew.jpg)

[File Explorer View of Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Dzz.jpg)

Strategies I've tried that haven't quite worked:

1. Downloading MSYS2 Ming32
2. Updating Chocolatey and executing choco install make
3. Downloading MakeFile extension on VisualStudioCode. Cannot figure out how to build target or launch target as only option to click is 'default'

Any suggestions as to what mistakes I am making or how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `include ../GNUmakefile` It's trying to include another file from the parent directory. And it is that one that doesn't exist.

Comment: This fixed the problem. I added GNUmakefile to the parent directory and it was able to find it. Thank you!